# Should I not be getting "fatal: pathspec 'file.txt' did not match any files" in this scenario?

Tags: git

I have a tracked file, "file.txt".  I decided to physically delete it using Windows file explorer.   Then I do a "git add file.txt".  Should this not trigger "fatal: pathspec 'file.txt' did not match any files" since the file no longer exists?

Answer (score 2):

No.  If you have a file in the index, and do *not* have the file in the working directory, then `git add` will *stage the deletion*.  (In other words, it behaves like `git rm`).

```
$ rm exists
$ git ls-files --stage exists
100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0   exists
$ git add exists
$ git ls-files --stage exists
$ ls -Flas exists
ls: exists: No such file or directory
```

However, if the file does not exist in either the index *or* the working directory, then git will error:

```
$ ls -Flas nonexistent
ls: nonexistent: No such file or directory
$ git ls-files --stage nonexistent
$ git add nonexistent
fatal: pathspec 'nonexistent' did not match any files
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should this not trigger "fatal: pathspec 'file.txt' did not match any files" since the file no longer exists?

**No, it should not.** `file.txt` is still a file that git is tracking, even if it doesn't exist in the local file system. It *did* exist, and then you deleted it. If you had run `git status` at that point, you'd see `file.txt` marked as deleted but not staged. When you run `git add file.txt`, and then `git status`, you'll see that `file.txt` is marked as deleted and staged. The next `git commit` will then add that change to the repository, so that the file won't show up in the repo beyond that commit.